# How can I measure the distance of two features within an image in R?

Tags: r, image, distance

I'm currently struggling with some image analysis. I have images of zebrafish embryo vasculature, and I want to measure the distance between certain features (the highest point to the lowest etc).
I have processed the images to be more visible (higher contrast) using EBImage
[image: as shown in image].

I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `R` and `EBImage`, I would presume that there is more analysis intended than just extracting measurements from an image. If that *is* all you intend, other software such as [Fiji](https://imagej.net/Fiji) or the more streamline precursor, [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/index.html), may be more user-friendly.

To answer the question, don't use `display()` for the image as you show here. Rather, use the `plot()` method that uses the option `method = raster` as the default. With the image plotted in a graphic window, you can use all the tools of `R` to interact with the plot. The resolution you have is determined by the size of your image and display. All values are returned in pixels and obviously need to be scaled appropriately.

This example uses `locator()` in a small helper function to measure diagonal distances between vascular junctions (?) in the image.

This simple helper function marks two points and measures the distance between the points. End the call to `locator()` with a right-click control-click or the escape key. In RStudio, you may have to explicitly press another button in the window and the points/lines may not be drawn until all calls to `locator()` are terminated.

```
  p2p <- function(n = 512) # end with ctrl-click or Esc
  {
    ans <- numeric()
    while (n > 0) {
    # this call to locator places 2 points as crosses
    # and connects them with a line
      p <- locator(2, type = "o", pch = 3, col = "magenta")
      if (is.null(p)) break
      ans <- c(ans, sqrt(sum(sapply(p, diff)^2)))
      n <- n - 1
    }
    return(ans) # return the vector of point-to-point distances
  }
```

Now replot the image in the question (without the elements from the browser display) and then interact with the image.

[image: original image]

```
  plot(img) # not 'display(img)'
  d <- p2p() # interact with the image, collecting distances
```

Here's the image after selecting six pairs of points with the distances measured between each pair of points.

[image: marked up fish]

```
  round(d, 1)
> [1] 113.4  99.2 109.4 110.8 120.6 122.7
  mean(d)
> 112.6736
```

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry for my dumb question , but is this distance measured in pixels ?

Answer (score 0):

Not dumb at all. Yes, it is in pixels—EBImage  and R gives you fractional pixels.